# How does "Miller–Rabin" primality test computed for big numbers?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, primality-test

According to [Primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test) Wikipedia page, Miller–Rabin primality test is described as;

> The Miller–Rabin primality test works as follows: Given an integer n,
>   choose some positive integer a < n. Let 2<sup>s</sup>d = n − 1, where
>   d is odd. If
>
> ${a}^{d} \not \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$
>
> and
>
> $a^{2^{r}d}\not \equiv -1{\pmod {n}}$ for all $0\leq r\leq s-1$,
>
> then n is composite and a is a witness for the compositeness.
>   Otherwise, n may or may not be prime. The Miller–Rabin test is a
>   strong pseudoprime test (see PSW[3] page 1004).

In applications like Cryptography, n is usually a very big number, 2048 bit number is not unusual. In the equation, 2<sup>s</sup>d = n − 1, when s is very small number like 1 or 2, d also have to be a very big number, it could have 2047 or 2046 significant bits.

In such cases, how is ${a}^{d} \not \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$ calculated, as resulting number has to be exponentially huge.

Comment: Are you aware of [modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation)? In general this needn't be much more than logarithmic in the exponent, once you fix the modulus.

Comment: In particular you never have to compute $a^d$ itself; by doing everything mod $n$ you never have to deal with numbers larger than $n$, and you don't need more than 2048 bits to represent them.  That's not so very big.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Binary exponentiation or exponentiation by squaring?